# Firmar Nodo especifico de un XML con php

Tags: php, xml

Mi problema yace, que necesito firmar solo el tag de *DE* del XML mediante certificados digitales, actualmente estoy probando con la librería *xmlseclibs*  [https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs].

Probé segmentando mi documento, pero al unir de nuevo, al validar, me genera que el PKI fue modificado, esto implica que el xml tuvo alguna alteración cuando no ocurre el mismo.

Investigando, encontré que el documento puede ser alterado al firmar por segmento, entonces, busque si la misma librería puede hacer referencia al Nodo que necesito firmar, y no lo logre.

````
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <rEnviDe xmlns="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd">
         <dId>100</dId>
         <iAmb>1</iAmb>
         <xDE>
          <rDE xmlns="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd siRecepDE_v150.xsd">
        <dVerFor>150</dVerFor>
        <DE Id="01800138848001001123456412018121817819792239">
        <dDVId>9</dDVId>
        <dFecFirma>2018-12-18T17:44:36</dFecFirma>
        <dSisFact>1</dSisFact>
        <gOpeDE>
            <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
            <dDesTipEmi>Normal</dDesTipEmi>
            <dCodSeg>781979223</dCodSeg>
            <dInfoEmi>a</dInfoEmi>
            <dInfoFisc>Información de interés del Fisco respecto al DE</dInfoFisc>
        </gOpeDE>
        <gTimb>
            <iTiDE>1</iTiDE>
            <dDesTiDE>Factura electrónica</dDesTiDE>
            <dNumTim>12557209</dNumTim>
            <dEst>001</dEst>
            <dPunExp>001</dPunExp>
            <dNumDoc>1234564</dNumDoc>
            <!--<dSerieNum>AA</dSerieNum>!-->
            <dFeIniT>2018-10-12</dFeIniT>
        </gTimb>
        <gDatGralOpe>
            <dFeEmiDE>2018-12-18T17:44:36</dFeEmiDE>
            <gOpeCom>
                <iTipTra>1</iTipTra>
                <dDesTipTra>Venta de mercadería</dDesTipTra>
                <iTImp>1</iTImp>
                <dDesTImp>IVA</dDesTImp>
                <cMoneOpe>PYG</cMoneOpe>
                <dDesMoneOpe>Guarani</dDesMoneOpe>
            </gOpeCom>
            <gEmis>
                <dRucEm>80013884</dRucEm>
                <dDVEmi>8</dDVEmi>
                <iTipCont>1</iTipCont>
                <dNomEmi>BANCARD S.A.</dNomEmi>
                <dNomFanEmi>BANCARD</dNomFanEmi>
                <dDirEmi>AVENIDA BRASILIA N° 765</dDirEmi>
                <dNumCas>1</dNumCas>
                <cDepEmi>1</cDepEmi>
                <dDesDepEmi>CAPITAL</dDesDepEmi>
                <cDisEmi>1</cDisEmi>
                <dDesDisEmi>ASUNCION (DISTRITO)</dDesDisEmi>
                <cCiuEmi>1</cCiuEmi>
                <dDesCiuEmi>ASUNCION (DISTRITO)</dDesCiuEmi>
                <dTelEmi>214161000</dTelEmi>
                <dEmailE>contabilidad@bancard.com.py</dEmailE>
                <gActEco>
                    <cActEco>64990</cActEco>
                    <dDesActEco>OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE SERVICIOS FINANCIEROS, EXCEPTO LA FINANCIACIÓN DE PLANES DE SEGUROS Y DE PENSIONES</dDesActEco>
                </gActEco>
            </gEmis>
            <gDatRec>
                <iNatRec>1</iNatRec>
                <iTiOpe>1</iTiOpe>
                <cPaisRec>PRY</cPaisRec>
                <dDesPaisRe>Paraguay</dDesPaisRe>
                <iTiContRec>2</iTiContRec>
                <dRucRec>80002201</dRucRec>
                <dDVRec>7</dDVRec>
                <dNomRec>BANCO DEL PARAGUAY S.A.</dNomRec>
                <dDirRec>YEGROS Y MCAL. LÓPEZ</dDirRec>
                <dNumCasRec>123</dNumCasRec>
                <dTelRec>21494992</dTelRec>
                <dCodCliente>AAA</dCodCliente>
            </gDatRec>
        </gDatGralOpe>
        <gDtipDE>
            <gCamFE>
                <iIndPres>1</iIndPres>
                <dDesIndPres>Operación presencial</dDesIndPres>
            </gCamFE>
            <gCamCond>
                <iCondOpe>2</iCondOpe>
                <dDCondOpe>Crédito</dDCondOpe>              
                <gPagCred>
                    <iCondCred>1</iCondCred>
                    <dDCondCred>Plazo</dDCondCred>
                    <dPlazoCre>28</dPlazoCre>
                </gPagCred>
            </gCamCond>
            <gCamItem>
                <dCodInt>CAC/CTAC</dCodInt>
                <dDesProSer>CUENTAS ACTIVAS</dDesProSer>
                <cUniMed>77</cUniMed>
                <dDesUniMed>UNI</dDesUniMed>
                <dCantProSer>423378</dCantProSer>
                <dInfItem>21</dInfItem>
                <gValorItem>
                    <dPUniProSer>125.94133776</dPUniProSer>
                    <dTotBruOpeItem>0</dTotBruOpeItem>
                    <gValorRestaItem>
                        <dDescItem>0</dDescItem>
                        <dPorcDesIt>100</dPorcDesIt>
                        <dTotOpeItem>53320791.70</dTotOpeItem>
                    </gValorRestaItem>                  
                </gValorItem>
                <gCamIVA>
                    <iAfecIVA>1</iAfecIVA>
                    <dDesAfecIVA>Gravado IVA</dDesAfecIVA>
                    <dPropIVA>100</dPropIVA>
                    <dTasaIVA>10</dTasaIVA>
                    <dBasGravIVA>48473447</dBasGravIVA>
                    <dLiqIVAItem>4847345</dLiqIVAItem>
                </gCamIVA>
            </gCamItem>
            <gCamItem>
                <dCodInt>TAU/TAUR</dCodInt>
                <dDesProSer>TARJETA URGENTE</dDesProSer>
                <cUniMed>77</cUniMed>
                <dDesUniMed>UNI</dDesUniMed>
                <dCantProSer>36</dCantProSer>
                <gValorItem>
                    <dPUniProSer>92015</dPUniProSer>
                    <dTotBruOpeItem>123</dTotBruOpeItem>
                    <gValorRestaItem>
                        <dDescItem>123</dDescItem>
                        <dPorcDesIt>0</dPorcDesIt>
                        <dTotOpeItem>3312540</dTotOpeItem>
                    </gValorRestaItem>
                </gValorItem>
                <gCamIVA>
                    <iAfecIVA>1</iAfecIVA>
                    <dDesAfecIVA>Gravado IVA</dDesAfecIVA>
                    <dPropIVA>100</dPropIVA>
                    <dTasaIVA>10</dTasaIVA>
                    <dBasGravIVA>3011400</dBasGravIVA>
                    <dLiqIVAItem>301140</dLiqIVAItem>
                </gCamIVA>
            </gCamItem>
            <gCamEsp>
                <gGrupAdi>
                    <dCiclo>DICIEMBRE</dCiclo>
                    <dFecIniC>2018-11-23</dFecIniC>
                    <dFecFinC>2018-12-17</dFecFinC>
                </gGrupAdi>
            </gCamEsp>
            <gTransp>
                <iModTrans>1</iModTrans>
                <dDesModTrans>Aéreo</dDesModTrans>
                <iRespFlete>2</iRespFlete>
                <dNuDespImp>1234567891asfdcs</dNuDespImp>
            </gTransp>
        </gDtipDE>
        <gTotSub>
            <dSubExe>0</dSubExe>
            <dSubExo>0</dSubExo>
            <dSub5>0</dSub5>
            <dSub10>0.0</dSub10>
            <dTotOpe>0.0</dTotOpe>
            <dTotDesc>0</dTotDesc>
            <dTotDescGlotem>0</dTotDescGlotem>
            <dTotAntItem>0</dTotAntItem>
            <dTotAnt>0</dTotAnt>
            <dPorcDescTotal>100</dPorcDescTotal>
            <dDescTotal>0.0</dDescTotal>
            <dAnticipo>0</dAnticipo>
            <dRedon>0.0</dRedon>
            <dTotGralOpe>0</dTotGralOpe>
            <dIVA5>0</dIVA5>
            <dIVA10>0</dIVA10>
            <dTotIVA>0</dTotIVA>
            <dBaseGrav5>0</dBaseGrav5>
            <dBaseGrav10>0</dBaseGrav10>
            <dTBasGraIVA>0</dTBasGraIVA>
        </gTotSub>
    </DE>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <Reference URI="#01800025776001001900018322018111317200146406">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue></DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>      
    <gCamFuFD>
        <dCarQR>https://ekuatia.set.gov.py/consultas-test/qr?nVersion=150&amp;Id=01800138848001001123456412018121817819792239&amp;dFeEmiDE=323031392d30342d30395431323a35373a3137&amp;dRucRec=80081294&amp;dTotGralOpe=0&amp;dTotIVA=0&amp;cItems=1&amp;DigestValue=5368453774502b6a74766a39662f4952734f7077694f366b574146346458366c487559547775556b304b4d3d&amp;IdCSC=0001&amp;cHashQR=3e4431dc88ee9c9c2b4037f40db15091c468bcc4a591c74c5d6a3e0b3a72aa40</dCarQR>
    </gCamFuFD>
</rDE>

         </xDE>
      </rEnviDe>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope> ```
````

Comment: amigo. lograste resolver? yo tengo un problema con los eventos. Me sale Valor de la firma (SignatureValue) diferente del calculado por el PKI. Sabes al

Comment: Si pude hacerlo, ¿Cómo estas tratando de resolver?, dependiendo del mismo, puedo ayudarte

Comment: @OrlandoMartínez Si has encontrado una solución deberías al menos responder la pregunta en la sección de respuestas explicando cómo lo conseguiste, así para que pueda servir de ayuda a los que tengan problemas similares.

Comment: ¡No olvides responder a tu pregunta, y luego [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta! Recordá que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser de utilidad no solo para vos, sino para los demás usuarios que tengan un problema similar (que te puedo asegurar que ya hubo gente con el mismo problema). No mantengas la respuesta en secreto ;)

Comment: La solución fue escapear los valores generados antes de firmar el documento, ya que, por alguna razon, la librería agregaba saltos de líneas al final del documento, antes de firmar